# Grading proofs without reading them?

Tags: grading

Is it unethical or illegal to grade a proof exam without reading all of the proofs? Someone I know would give students 0 points if they do not use theorems presented in lectures, or if they have one solution that solves multiple problems at once will ignore it. Also would make up criteria to fit his/her own agenda for punishing students. Then he/she would leave it up to the students to possibly argue for changes in office hours. Is there some standard criteria for grading proofs, either on a legal or professional level?

Comment: I think the question of whether this is *legal* is off-topic here, in addition to being unanswerable without knowing your jurisdiction.  But in general, most legal systems don't try to get involved in the details of academia at this level.

Comment: It is ok to agree to be convinced that one graded an exam wrongly. However, making this the default procedure for treating deviations from the "standard" solution is bad teaching.

Comment: This feels more of a rant than an honest question.

Comment: @Davidmh It was meant to be an honest uestion but my emotions got the better of me in the execution of the text. Grading/correcting policies are definintely on topic.

Answer (score 9):

Based strictly on the information you have provided to me about this mystery person, I'd say the instructor engaging in these activities is highly unethical and may have some other psychological issues. That's just what I sense "prima facie". "Absolute power corrupts absolutely", but I could easily be wrong.

Then again, maybe the mystery person has explained the grading criteria, but hasn't explained it clearly enough.

Be very careful about making a formal accusation against this person. If you make an accusation, make sure it's iron-clad and infallible so that you're certain to win.

Many years ago, in an Engineering Mechanics class, I openly accused my professor of erring in his solution to an exam question. My exam question was marked as "incorrect" with very little partial credit. I stared at that problem for some time and concluded my solution was correct and the professor's was wrong. I treaded very gingerly as I described my disagreement with his solution, but I went step by step and ultimately, before the entire class, he admitted he was wrong and I was right.

I was about 18 or 19 years old at the time. Trust me. Be very careful. Professors are smart and they don't like to be proven wrong. My professor was, thankfully, **a person who loved truth more than being correct**.

Comment: *"highly unethical"* and *"psychological issues"* -- please don't go slinging such baseless accusations. The question is very incoherent and sounds exactly like every grade grubber. This "answer" is clearly just you projecting your own feelings of being slighted that you've never gotten over.

Comment: I have heard rumors that in some countries it is standard practice to only accept answers that are exactly the same as the answer in the textbook, even if there are obviously many correct answers.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: not exactly, I think. It's Inquisitive interpreting what would have to be the case in order for the questioner's description to be accurate and a fair representation. There's a subtext here: "if this person isn't highly unethical, then *you* are not giving us the full picture".

Comment: For example, "give students 0 points if they do not use theorems presented in lectures" is presented by the questioner without context and may appear arbitrary. But if the assignment is to prove X from theorem Y, and you choose instead to prove X from some other more powerful theorem not covered in lectures, certainly you've failed the assignment, and the questioner perhaps doesn't fully understand this. Or perhaps does understand it, and is trying find justification on the interwebs for exactly the grade grubbing behaviour you accuse them of.

Comment: Likewise, "makes up criteria to fit agenda for punishing students" is bad if accurate, but the actual situation might be that the criteria are pretty common and/or a reasonable interpretation of the assignments given, but didn't go in the questioner's favour. As long as the "agenda" is to "punish students" in the sense of giving them 0 marks for garbage answers it'd be OK. Inquisitive does say the answer is a remark on the prima facie picture the questioner paints, not on whether that picture is correct.

Comment: @Chris White You need to stop being a "Sheldon" and start exhibiting some reading comprehension capability.

Comment: @ Steve Jessop You are exactly correct in interpreting what I wrote. Unfortunately, Chris White seems to be the one wildly drawing fallacious conclusions.

Comment: Yes, I'd second the point that if your prof loves truth more than "being correct", then things will turn out ok if everyone is reasonably polite! :)

Answer (score 8):

It is not necessarily wrong for a proof to be marked wrong without reading the whole thing. If it sets out to prove the wrong thing, it is wrong. If it starts at the conclusion and works towards the hypothesis (a very common mistake) it is wrong. If it assumes something incorrect, or simply not shown, that makes it easier to arrive at a proof, it is wrong for the purpose of the assessment. If it proves multiple things at once, it is almost certainly wrong, in such a context. If it is illegible it could get no marks regardless of other factors. If it is correct but hard to read, it may be worth no marks if that was the assessment criterion.

And, no, there is no universal mark scheme. For anything (at university level).